# python deepnl library, Runtime Error

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have downloaded the Python `deepnl` library from https://github.com/attardi/deepnl
and made sure I have all the dependencies installed: `numpy`, `Eigen` and `Cython`.
When I try to build the library with

```
python setup.py build
```

I get a Runtime Error

> An attempt has been made to start the new process before the before the current process has finished its boostrapping phase.
>   This probably means that you are not using fork to start your child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom in the main module:
>   if **name**= '**main**':
>       freeze_support()"

What's going on here?